# How to wire null as method parameter with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to call a custom method with null parameter. I am trying to use arguments property with  element. But I am getting below error. Is there any way to do this?

```
<bean id="customJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="customExecutor" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="run" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <null/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am getting below error;

```
Error creating bean with name 'customJob'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: total.scheduler.CustomExecutor.run()
```

My CustomExecutor class method;

```
public void run(Object object){
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
<bean id="customJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="customExecutor" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="run" />
    <property name="arguments">

    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <null/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```